# PHP MySQL Query Multiple Values then Compare to HTML Input then echo based on each result

Tags: php, mysql

So, on HTML form, on submit, I want it to check if a couple of different values exist and echo something different based on different values.

For instance (SQL which receives input from different page):

```
public function getOrderByRMA($rma_num, $regpro_sn) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "reg_product ";
    $sql .= " WHERE rma_num = '". $rma_num ."' AND ";
    $sql .= "regpro_sn = '". $regpro_sn ."' ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->row['rma_num_status']=0){
        $validity = 0;
    } elseif ($query->row['rma_num_status']=2) {
        $validity = 1;
    } elseif ($query->row['rma_num_status']=3) {
        $validity = 2;
    }
    else {
        return $query->row;
    }
}
```

From the table "reg_product" there is "rma_num", "regpro_sn" and "rma_num_status"

I want it to check the input of user for "rma_num" to ensure that it matches with what is in the database WHERE the "regpro_sn" matches with the "regpro_sn" on the HTML form ("regpro_sn" would be specific to individual users only)

but at the same time, check what the value of "rma_num_status" is which could be "0", "1", "2", or "3"

PHP Page that interprets the data from SQL:

```
protected function validateForm() {
    $rma_num_check = $this->model_account_order->getOrderByRMA($this->request->post['ticket'],$this->request->post['regpro_sn']);
    if ( empty($rma_num_check) ) {
        $this->error['error_rma'] = $this->language->get('error_rma_none');
    } elseif ($validity == 1){
        $this->error['error_rma'] = $this->language->get('error_rma');
    } elseif ($validity == 2){
        $this->error['error_rma'] = $this->language->get('error_rma_invalid');
    }
   }
```

I do not know how to define a variable within a SELECT '*' to check if it = something specific.

Thanks for the help

Comment: should the second block be php or in the sql statement? (It's a bit hard to understand what you wanna do)

Comment: and what do you meen with _"how to define a variable within a SELECT"_?

Comment: you should be checking the status on the PHP side, not on the SQL .. don't overcomplicate your life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to conditionalize the select statement, which you can do using the CASE syntax

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN rma_num_status = 1 THEN ''
            WHEN rma_num_status = 2 THEN 'Already in use'
            WHEN rma_num_status = 3 THEN 'No longer Valid'
            ELSE 'RMA Number was not found'
        END CASE as 'status'
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "reg_product 
    WHERE rma_num = '". $rma_num ."'
    AND regpro_sn = '". $regpro_sn ."'
";
```

If you trying to do something else, post your database table create statements and an example of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: made an update to my code. Your post is close to what I am looking for.

Comment: It seems like you need to return $query->row['rma_num_status']

Comment: I see where you are going with this but now I get "Notice: Undefined index: rma_num_status in /home/tplinkus/public_html/test/catalog/model/account/order.php on line 252"

Comment: can you print_r($query->row);

Comment: so it is returning an empty row. Have you tried outputting $sql and running that directly against your db?

Comment: if you var_dump($sql) and var_dump($query), it may help point us in the right direction